# Relative speed of satellites in different orbits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, relative-motion

The question is

> "The Hubble Space Telescope is in orbit around the Earth at a height of 560km above the Earth’s surface. Take the radius and mass of the Earth to be 6.4×10^ 6m and 6.0×10^24 kg, respectively. In a servicing mission, a Space Shuttle spots the Hubble telescope a distance of 10km ahead. Estimate how long it took the Shuttle to catch up with Hubble, assuming that the Shuttle was moving in a circular orbit just 500m below Hubble’s orbit."

The answer involves finding the relative speed of the satellites and then dividing 10 km by this relative speed to find the time it takes the shuttle to catch up to the Hubble telescope.

I am familiar with relative speed in straight lines, but I was wondering if this was also applicable to circular orbits? I have tried to understand this, but I keep getting confused about whether this method of solving the question is valid. Also, the question doesn't specify whether the 10 km is measured along the Hubble's orbit or the shuttle's orbit. Even if they did give this information wouldn't this be a contradiction because the answer should change depending on if the 10 km is measured along either orbit?

Comment: I believe the question is aiming for an approximation only, since 500m is very little compared to 560km, it doesn't matter if the 10km ahead are a straight line or along one or the other orbit.

Comment: The problem is ill-stated.  If the SS is going to change altitude, that requires some serious math to figure the burn to apogee, etc.  If the problem just means "SS is verticallly directly under Hubble" then just use orbital speeds and circumferences.

Comment: Yes I also believe the problem is more complex than it is stated. But you CAN approximate the time as stated by the OP. One is assuming that their relative speeds will be constant through out the procedure and that they are mostly given by their tangential component.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense; I forgot to take into account the fact that it was only a difference in 500 m which means it could be approximated to a straight line. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to compute the tangential speed of each, just by using the radius of their orbit (earth radius + orbit distance) and the mass of the Earth. Equating gravitational force with centripetal acceleration you immediately have:
$$G \frac{Mm}{r^2} = m\frac{v^2}{r}$$
which you can use for each object and solve for $v$.